# How to solve this limit 2 variables $\lim_{(x,y) \to (4,1)} \frac{y \sqrt x - 2y - \sqrt x + 2}{4 - x + x \sqrt y - 4 \sqrt y}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Please anybody can help me solve this?

$$\lim \frac{y \sqrt x - 2y - \sqrt x + 2}{4 - x + x \sqrt y - 4 \sqrt y}$$
with $(x,y) \to (4,1)$

Thank you!

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{y\sqrt x-2y-\sqrt x+2}{4-x+x\sqrt y-4 \sqrt y}=\frac{\sqrt x (y-1)-2(y-1)}{\sqrt y(x-4)-(x-4)}=\frac{(y-1)(\sqrt x-2)}{(x-4)(\sqrt y-1)}=\frac{\sqrt y+1}{\sqrt x+2}$$

You can show that the function $f(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt y+1}{\sqrt x+2}$ is continuous at the point $(x,y)=(4,1)$ :
$$|f(x,y)-f(4,1)|=|\frac{\sqrt y+1}{\sqrt x+2}-\frac{1}{2}|=|\frac{2\sqrt y+2-\sqrt x-2}{2(\sqrt x+2)}|\leq \frac{2|\sqrt y-1|+|2-\sqrt x|}{2(\sqrt x+2)}<\epsilon$$ for $\|(x,y)-(4,1)\|_{l^2}$ small enough.

So the limit really exists and it is $f(4,1)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Nice factoring.